# Replicating the sleight of hand Trick Oil and Water

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Note: I haven't found an answer to this particular question.

Backstory:

I recently learned the Oil and Water routine that magician's use in sleight of hand (this doesn't mean I can actually do it, but I have the mechanics done). For those that are unfamiliar with this routine, it takes three red cards and three black cards. These cards are initially put together red, black, red, black, red, black. By the end of the trick, all the reds are back together and all the blacks are back together.

I have successfully coded this in Java, but I am at a loss as to explain why it is doing it correctly. I think there is a problem with my logic I am sure, but I need some verification.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
  int[] mixed = {1,2,1,2,1,2};

    System.out.println("Before Sort: ");
    for (int element : mixed){
        System.out.println("Element: " + element);
    }

   for  (int element : mixed){//this for loop moves all but the first and last element.
  //  for (int element=0;element < mixed.length-1;element++){// this for loop reverses order 
        int temp = mixed[element];
        mixed[element]=mixed[element+1];
        mixed[element+1]=temp;
    }

    if ((mixed[0]==1) && (mixed[5]==2)){//this swaps the first and last elements after using an enhanced for loop

        int temp = mixed[0];
        mixed[0] = mixed[5];
        mixed[5] = temp;
    }

    System.out.println("After sort: ");
    for (int element : mixed){
        System.out.println("Element: " + element);
    }
```

Make sure to read the comments I have in the code, as this is where my wtf moment is. My goal is to be able to have my high school students do this when it comes time to hit arrays. I would like to be able to introduce this as I introduce arrays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you got it to work I sure sketching the iterations in a piece of paper will get you there. Kinda weird to be asking for an explanation of something that works that you did. We all have our "Attempt Oriented Programming" but after it works it's time to sleep and use the debugger in the next morning...

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)  The code you've posted is not compilable (see [mcve]). Have you tried stepping through the code in an IDE debugger yet?  That's pretty much a prerequisite before posting, and then you could pinpoint what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the array using elements of the array as an index for the switches that you make.

You are only ever doing two of the same switches.

1. When the current element is 1, it switches values at index 1 and index 2 of the array.
2. When the current element is 2, it switches values at index 2 and index 3 of the array.

This doesn't work; you have to do a manual switch at the end. And this manual switch will not work in other cases.

The right way to do this is to:

```
array 1 2 1 2 1 2
index 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Switch:

1. 0 with 1
2. 1 with 3
3. 2 with 5

The are only 3 switches so the loop should start at 0 and end at array length / 2.